# python matplotlib the relationship between colormap and vmax/vmin

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am new on python matplotlib, i am trying different setting on `cmp` and `vmax`,`vmin`

For my understanding if the result higher than `vmax` ,the result show the end of the colormap(dark) and the result lower then the `vmin` the result shows the original of the colormap(light) like pic1
[image: pic1]

But when i set the `vmax` or `vmin` out of the result,how the color resconding to the result??why it shows like this?

such as when i set the `vmin` out of the range and the result show the bule but there's no blue in my `cmp` see pic2
[image: pic2]

and when the `vmax` out of the range the result show the light color,for my understanding the color should be the same as `cmp=plt.cm.Greens` see pic3
[image: pic3]

i upload the pic.
Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


num=range(1,100)
out=[x**2 for x in num]
plt.figure(figsize=(11, 11))


plt.title('Scatter',size=24)
plt.ylabel('Result',size=24)
plt.xlabel('Number',size=24)
plt.axis([0, 110, 0, 11000])

plt.scatter(num,out,s=50,lw=2,c=out,cmap=plt.cm.Greens,marker='o',label='Scatter',vmin=99999)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to see what's happening, is to add a colorbar (`plt.colorbar()`, after creating the scatter plot). You'll note that your `out` values between 0 and 10000 are all below the lowest part of the bar, where things are a very light green.

In general, values below `vmin` will be colored with the lowest color, and values above `vmax` will get the highest color.

If you set `vmax` smaller than `vmin`, internally they will be swapped. Although, depending on the exact version of matplotlib and the precise functions called, matplotlib might give an error warning. So, best to set `vmin` always lower than `vmax`.

If you don't set `vmin`, it will be calculated automatically as the minimum of the data. Similarly, if you don't set `vmax`, it will be set to the maximum of the data. So, in case you set `vmin=99999` and don't set `vmax`, `vmax` will be calculated as 10000. As now `vmax < vmin`, matplotlib will swap them, so you end with `vmin=10000 and`vmax=99999`, as shown in the colorbar.

If you don't set a colormap (`cmap=`), matplotlib will automatically use ['viridis'](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).  This colormap has a dark purple/blue color near `vmin`.

If you don't set the `c=` parameter, the color is taken from the [default property cycle](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/color_cycle_default.html). So, the first time it is called a blue color, the next time orange, then green, then red, ... . There are 10 colors, after which the colors start again from the blue. (The colormap is called 'tab10' in current versions of matplotlib.) Note that `vmin` and `vmax` are ignored if you don't set the `c=`.

In the code below, I added a red line where the `out` values belong into the colorbar.  You can experiment with different values for vmin and vmax to see what happens.  Usually, the easiest is to not fill them in and let matplotlib calculate them automatically.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num = range(1, 100)
out = [x ** 2 for x in num]
plt.figure(figsize=(11, 11))

plt.title('Scatter', size=24)
plt.ylabel('Result', size=24)
plt.xlabel('Number', size=24)
plt.axis([0, 110, 0, 11000])

plt.scatter(num, out, s=50, lw=2, c=out, cmap=plt.cm.Greens, marker='o', label='Scatter', vmin=99999)
# plt.colorbar()
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.vlines(1, min(out), max(out), color='crimson', lw=3, clip_on=False)
plt.show()
```

In the plot below three situations are depicted:

```py
#left plot ('c=' set to 'out', 'cmap=' set to 'Greens')
plt.scatter(num, out, s=50, lw=2, c=out, cmap=plt.cm.Greens, marker='o', vmin=99999)
#central plot ('c=' not set, 'cmap=' not set)
plt.scatter(num, out, s=50, lw=2, marker='o', vmin=99999)
#right plot ('c=' set to 'out', 'cmap=' not set)
plt.scatter(num, out, s=50, lw=2, c=out, marker='o', vmin=99999)
```

[image: comparison plot]

Comment: Is that when i set the ```Vmin``` > ```Vmax```matplotlib swap them,so that if i only set one```Vmin=9999``` or ```Vmax=9999```,finally the reslut should be the same as ```Vmax=9999```&```Vmin=out``` , and when I add ```cbar = plt.colorbar()``` to check the color, the diffferent color in ```Vmin=9999```,light green with ```plt.colorbar()```[i know this is correct], blue without ```plt.colorbar()```[this confused me]

Comment: If you don't put a colorbar, the image will be the same, the colorbar is just a help to see what is happening.  If you don`t give a colormap (`cmap=`), matplotlib chooses [viridis](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). Viridis has a dark blue-purple color near vmin,